# Adding comments to keywords for better understanding in RF

Tags: python, output, robotframework

Is there any way we can add comments to keywords for better understanding the test step in RF ?

Can we achieve this without customizing the Selenium2Library ?

Eg - Click Element   id=loginButton . We want to add a comment in the log.html file "Trying to click login button"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's what "[Builtin.Comment](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Comment)" was created for.

```
Comment            Trying to click login button
Click Element      id=loginButton
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this will show as 2 steps in the log.html file. 
The 1st step will be 
"BuitIn.Comment - Trying to click login button"
and the 2nd step will be 
"Selenium2Library - Clicking id= LoginButton"

I want to show it has one step. Is that possible without customizing the libraries?

Comment: No. But `Click Elemment` (and all other keywords) already have a comment under "Documentation" field in the log. F.e. you can see `Click element identified by "locator"` under `Click Element`.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` character can be used for comments. This is mentioned in the [Rules for parsing](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rules-for-parsing-the-data) section of the robot framework user guide.

```
*** Keywords ***
Example keyword
    # comments can be on a line by themself
    one keyword

    another keyword  # or inline, as long as they start in a new cell.
```

If you want the comment to appear in the log, you can use the [comment](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Comment) keyword, which will appear the same as any other keyword in the log. You can also use the [log](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log) keyword to get the same effect.

```
*** Keywords ***
Example keyword
    comment  this will appear as a step in the log
    log      this will also appear as a step in the log
```

There is no other way to inject information into the log.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see in the log file an entry "Trying to click login button" when yo do that click, as separate and top-level one - wrap the actual action in a keyword with that name:

```
*** Keywords ***
Trying to click login button
    Click Element      id=loginButton
```

Thus the log will have the user-friendly naming, not the actual selenium call.
It might be an overkill for a single operation, but it makes the log much more comprehensible and easier to follow, especially for non-technical team members (PM, techpub, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `[Documentation]`

```
*** Keywords ***
Create Perf Streams
[Documentation]  Creates minimal length Performance UDP Streams
```

Other tools will resolve this field to create nice auto documentation of Libs